# Is the whole MHC haplotype expressed and so their proteins are exhibited on each nucleated cell membrane?

Tags: immunology, mhc

Am I correct if I guess the following (?):

If we inherit both maternal and paternal MHC haplotypes, the functional (non-pseudo)genes are expressed and all of their products (MHC molecules) are exhibited on the cytoplasmic membrane of any nucleated cell.

In case of MHC type I molecules our all nucleated cells bear one (or more? how many?) types of polypeptide(s) (corresponding to and) encoded by the inherited allels of each of A, B, C, E, F, G MHC-I [genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_and_naming_of_human_leukocyte_antigens#Current_HLA_naming_system).

In other words each nucleated cell expresses all MHC type I molecules encoded by our inherited MHC haplotype.

Is it true?

Thank you.